# Change unchecked state color of Vuetify radio button

Tags: javascript, css, radio-button, vuetify.js

How to change the **unchecked state color** of a [Vuetify radio button](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/radio-buttons/#usage) and add a background color?
(Currently it is just a grey outline. I need to change the outline and background color.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vuetify uses an SVG icon to render the radio button and the icon itself is just a circular outline. It inherits the current color of the parent element. Therefore, to change the outline color, you simply need to define a CSS `color` property on the radio's icon element.

```
.v-radio .v-icon {
   color: red;
}
```

Since the SVG icon is only an outline, it is not possible to change the background without modifying the parent node, because the parent node is just a square. You can change the background color, but you'll have to apply some additional styles to change the container shape to a circle and restrict the fill to the boundaries of the circle outline. A solid background color will bleed outside the bounds of the SVG circle, so a radial-gradient can be used to effectively "shrink" the fill to the desired size.

```
.v-radio .v-icon {
   color: red;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background-image: radial-gradient(blue 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

*Note: You'll need to use an `!important` flag on the primary color of the icon if you want to it to affect the **checked state** because Vuetify will use one for the primary color when the radio is checked. (I understand the OP specifically asked about the unchecked state, but I wanted to point this out for future visitors as well).*